# Problem loading the website using Firebase when using Burp Proxy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, burp

Let's say I use the website: redacted.com
Website works fine when I am using it normally.
When I start using BURP SUITE PROXY to intercept requests, I start to have this error:

[image: IMAGE-WITH-ERROR]

```
[2021-04-14T02:45:46.724Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.24.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
```

Please provide me the solution to this.

Comment: Have you turned interceptor on(in burp)?

Comment: Intercept is "off" so that I don't have to "forward" the request each time. However proxy is on and is intercepting. I am able to see things in **Proxy History** Tab and **Flow** extension.

Comment: Can you also provide logs in browsers network tab?

Comment: When does browser Network tab gives logs?

Comment: These logs are provided from Console tab in browser

Comment: I know those logs were from console. But the complete network logs can be found only in network tab. To capture that, you need to open dev tools before you open the site(atleast before the api call)

Answer (score 3):

The answers do not work anymore due to the Firebase updates - i will give you a short instruction on how to find your custom match-replace rule:

- make sure to activate "Intercept Server Responses" in the proxy options tab.
- go "intercept" tab
- set your burp proxy to "intercept is on"
- type "this.forceLongPolling" in the search bar on the bottom
- forward the requests until you find a match
- there should be a pretty big response file containing something like this:

```
constructor(t,o,u,p,D,Q,Te,it){
    this.databaseId=t,this.appId=o,this.persistenceKey=u,this.host=p,this.ssl=D,this.forceLongPolling=Q,this.autoDetectLongPolling=Te,this.useFetchStreams=it
}
```

- in my case it contains the string "this.forceLongPolling=Q"
- now create a match replace rule for this very special string to replace "this.forceLongPolling=Q" with "this.forceLongPolling=true" and make sure to choose "response body" as type:

[Screenshot Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVspf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea of this troubleshoot (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1190#), i made the following Match and Replace in my Burp Suite and it worked!

```
this.forceLongPolling=void 0!==t.experimentalForceLongPolling&&t.experimentalForceLongPolling
```

to

```
this.forceLongPolling=true
```

And someone said before

This can change depending on the version of firebase-js-sdk so it's best to look around for experimentalForceLongPolling within your JS files and make sure it gets enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this issue ([source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1190#issuecomment-552528853)).

For Burp, the following match and replace worked for me:

```
this.experimentalForceLongPolling=!!t.experimentalForceLongPolling
```

to

```
this.experimentalForceLongPolling=true
```

This can change depending on the version of `firebase-js-sdk` so it's best to look around for `experimentalForceLongPolling` within your JS files and make sure it gets enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. What worked for me is adding “firestore.googleapis.com” to the “No proxy for” option in Firefox’s proxy configuration.

[Firefox Proxy Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqiyI.png)